# Valgrind installation errors on OSX 10.8

Tags: c, macos, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, valgrind

Hi so I've been trying to Valgrind on mountain lion. I followed the instructions on valgrind's webpage:
http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/dist.install.html

As well as the instructions on this blog:
http://prateekvjoshi.com/2013/02/27/how-to-install-valgrind-on-mac-os-x/

But in either case I get the same errors when I attempt to 'make' or 'make install':

```
make[3]: *** [libcoregrind_amd64_darwin_a-m_syscall.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Does anyone know what these errors could mean? I couldn't find any help on it, even on valgrind's FAQ. Any help would be great.

---

Also, there were a few more lines of error that came right before the ones I mentioned above in case it's helpful:

```
m_syscall.c:525:1: error: unknown type name '__private_extern__'
m_syscall.c:526:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'do_syscall_unix_WRK'
m_syscall.c:549:1: error: unknown type name '__private_extern__'
m_syscall.c:550:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'do_syscall_mach_WRK'
m_syscall.c: In function 'vgPlain_do_syscall':
m_syscall.c:703:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'do_syscall_unix_WRK' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
m_syscall.c:708:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'do_syscall_mach_WRK' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From: http://jeetworks.org/node/151:
This error:

```
m_syscall.c:525:1: error: unknown type name '__private_extern__'
m_syscall.c:526:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'do_syscall_unix_WRK'
m_syscall.c:549:1: error: unknown type name '__private_extern__'
m_syscall.c:550:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'do_syscall_mach_WRK'
m_syscall.c: In function 'vgPlain_do_syscall':
m_syscall.c:703:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'do_syscall_unix_WRK' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
m_syscall.c:708:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'do_syscall_mach_WRK' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
make[3]: *** [libcoregrind_amd64_darwin_a-m_syscall.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This can be fixed by adding the line:

```
#define __private_extern__ extern
```

to the following files:

- `coregrind/m_syscall.c`
- `coregrind/m_syswrap/syswrap-darwin.c`
- `coregrind/vg_preloaded.c`

(Found this by Googling for : `unknown type name '__private_extern__' valgrind`)

Comment: Thanks! Here's how to automate that: for file in coregrind/m_syscall.c coregrind/m_syswrap/syswrap-darwin.c coregrind/vg_preloaded.c; do awk 'NR == 1 { print "#define __private_extern__ extern"; } { print }' $file > $file.new; mv $file.new $file; done